# Adjust a 22-line JS function that now returns wrong counts with +1 / +2 differences for no reasons

Tags: javascript

My function further below seems fine yet the count is overstated in some instances, eg: should count '1' but shows '2'.
Data source for context:

```
{
        "currency": "USD",
        "services": [
          {
            "category": [
              {"token": "token1"},
              {"token": "token2"}
            ],
            "price": 149
          },
          {
            "category": [
              {"token": "token3"},
              {"token": "token4"}
            ],
            "price": 149
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "services": [
          {
            "category": [
              {"token": "token1"},
              {"token": "token2"}
            ],
            "price": 149
          },
          {
            "category": [
              {"token": "token3"},
              {"token": "token4"}
            ],
            "price": 149
          }
```

Goal: COUNT the frequency of category tokens **per price**, sorted by currency in their own objects.

Desired output schema (for illustration purposes, unrelated to above schema example):

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "currency": "USD",
      "token": "Wellness",
      "count": 1,
      "price": 100
    },
    {
      "currency": "USD",
      "token": "Adventure",
      "count": 1,
      "price": 300
    }
  ]
}
```

It appears that sometimes, the count is not right, by +1 or +2 difference for no apparent reasons.
My function, which outputs wrong counts:

```
const data = inputs.data;
  const result = [];
  let error = null;

  try {
    data.forEach(item => {
      item.services.forEach(service => {
        service.category.forEach(tokenObject => {
          const token = tokenObject.token;
          const existingToken = result.find(item => item.token === token && item.price === service.price && item.currency === item.currency);
          if (existingToken) {
           existingToken.count++;
          } else {
          result.push({currency: item.currency, token, count: 1, price: service.price});
         }
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    error = "error";
  }
  return error ? [1, {error}] : [0, {result}]
```

Any way to make it "fool-proof" with some kind of "UNIQUE" safe guard?
Note: I'm **beginner** in JS.

Comment: There's probably a reason. It'd be easier to diagnose if there was example data that produced an incorrect result and the function in context--you might consider updating the question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a code snippet.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks but no clue what's code snippet and how to use it, sorry. My first impression is that the function counts per price AND per currency sometimes.

Comment: @FredK If you follow that link, it has a link to the explanation of code snippets. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: I guess it's already game over. I use a no code framework, no access to html, etc... Bummer...

Comment: I don't see "Wellness" and "Adventure" anywhere in your input data, but you have them in your desired output data.

Comment: @FredK It’s JavaScript—that’s code. SO snippets can run JS. But how will you run JS if there’s no code? 

Comment: @DaveNewton haha my dear, you made me laugh.The framework has various modules that enables light JS input code and run it "under the hood". So I see very little about what's going on in the background. I've read the instructions kindly shared by Barmar but it is too much code handling for me. I do not have the ability to access the code source like html, css... But guess what,I have use the OpenAI playground and it fixed my function perfectly! :) Amazing stuff. Let me share it here.

Comment: The code in your post is a chunk of JS. SO code snippets run JS. There’s no need for any HTML or CSS.

Comment: @DaveNewton I see, so you mean that I could just copy-paste the JS code that I posted in my question in the snippet and share it to you guys?

Answer (score 0):

I've used OpenAI's playground and it gave me the right function!
It suggested to "modify the existing code to use a Map data structure instead of an array to store the token count information. The Map will allow to keep track of each token, currency, and price combination as a key, and its count as the value"

```
const data = inputs.data;
  const result = [];
  let error = null;

 try {
  const tokenMap = new Map();
  data.forEach(item => {
    item.services.forEach(service => {
      service.category.forEach(tokenObject => {
        const token = tokenObject.token;
        const key = `${token}-${service.price}-${item.currency}`;
        if (tokenMap.has(key)) {
          tokenMap.set(key, tokenMap.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
          tokenMap.set(key, 1);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  tokenMap.forEach((count, key) => {
    const [token, price, currency] = key.split('-');
    result.push({currency, token, count, price: Number(price)});
  });

} catch (e) {
    error = "error";
  }
  return error ? [1, {error}] : [0, {result}]
```